# Question about the Cayley proof of the Jacobi triple product relation

Tags: power-series, infinite-product, q-series

In a stage of proving the Jacobi triple product identity, I have to prove this :

For $|z|<1$ and $|q|<1$, we set $F_0(z,q)=1$ and $F_m(z,q)=\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{1-q^kz}$.

If $(E_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of functions such that $\sum_{m=0}^\infty E_m(q)$ is absolutely convergent for any $|q|<1$, and if
$$(\forall(z,q)\in\mathbb C^2)\ (|z|<1 \text{ and }|q|<1)\Longrightarrow \sum_{m=0}^\infty E_m(q)z^mF_m(z)=0$$then $E_m(q)=0$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$ and all $|q|<1$.

All I have is the relation
$$F_m(zq,q)=(1-zq)\left[F_m(z,q)+zq^{m+1}F_{m+1}(z,q)\right]$$
and I don't even know how to use it (if it can be used). And the basic tool I'm allowed to use is the fact that if a power series cancels on a vicinity of $0$, then it's the null power series.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate your proof a bit more? In particular why do you need the result related to $E_m(q) $? Are you trying to prove the Jacobi identity analytically instead of treating as formal series / product?

Comment: I'm trying to answer an exercise that shows the Cayley demonstration of the Jacobi identity. I suppose I will have to use the functional identity verified by F to arrive at a null sum, giving me the possibility to identify the coefficients. I don't have much more clues...

Comment: You may have a look at the proof by Jacobi himself at https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0